# Compare Word documents without tracking formatting changes

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx

I have written a VBA routine for comparing docx files and saving the delta. I need to deactivate `TrackFormatting` in the delta but adding `.trackFormatting = False` does not do anything. In the compare method the CompareFormatting is false as well! How should I do this?

```
Sub ProduceDeltas()
   Dim strFolderA As String
   Dim strFolderB As String
   Dim strFolderC As String
   Dim strFileSpec As String
   Dim strFileName As String
   Dim objDocA As Word.Document
   Dim objDocB As Word.Document
   Dim objDocC As Word.Document
   Dim dc As Word.Document
   Dim FldrPickerInputA As FileDialog
   Dim FldrPickerInputB As FileDialog
   Dim FldrPickerOutput As FileDialog
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set FldrPickerInputA = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  Set FldrPickerInputB = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  Set FldrPickerOutput = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPickerInputA
  .Title = "Choose first file: "
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    strFolderA = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
   End With
   With FldrPickerInputB
  .Title = "Choose second file: "
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    strFolderB = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
   End With
  With FldrPickerOutput
  .Title = "Choose output file: "
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    strFolderC = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
 End With  

 NextCode:
 strFolderA = strFolderA
 strFolderB = strFolderB
 strFolderC = strFolderC
 If strFolderA = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
 strFileSpec = "*.docx"
 strFileName = Dir(strFolderA & strFileSpec)
 Do While strFileName <> vbNullString
 Set objDocA = Documents.Open(strFolderA & strFileName)
 Set objDocB = Documents.Open(strFolderB & strFileName)
 If objDocA.TablesOfContents.Count = 1 Then _
   objDocA.TablesOfContents(1).Update
 If objDocB.TablesOfContents.Count = 1 Then _
   objDocB.TablesOfContents(1).Update
 Set dc = Application.CompareDocuments(objDocA, objDocB,           wdCompareDestinationNew, _
   Granularity:=wdGranularityWordLevel, _
   CompareFormatting:=False, RevisedAuthor:="IQTIG",        CompareFootnotes:=False,   CompareHeaders:=False)

dc.TrackFormatting = False
objDocA.Save
objDocB.Save
objDocA.Close
objDocB.Close

If dc.TablesOfContents.Count = 1 Then _
 dc.TablesOfContents(1).Update

dc.SaveAs strFolderC & strFileName
dc.Close SaveChanges:=False
strFileName = Dir
Loop

Set objDocA = Nothing
Set objDocB = Nothing

ResetSettings: 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Word?  On Word 2013, `CompareFormatting:=False` works for me.

One option is to accept (or reject) all formatting revisions after running the comparison.  Before `dc.SaveAs`, insert the following:

```
dim oRevision as Revision
For Each oRevision In dc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Revisions
    If (oRevision.Type<> wdRevisionInsert) and (oRevision.type <> wdRevisionDelete) then
        oRevision.Accept    ' or .Reject
    End If
Next oRevision
```

(code modified from ExtractTrackedChangesToNewDoc by [Lene Fredborg](http://www.thedoctools.com/index.php?show=macros&lang=us), supplied as-is with no warranty.)